# Axis2 - making .aar archive problem with folder structure

Tags: apache-axis

i want to create a .aar archive from a simple service with following folder structure.
Folder Structure is as follows

```
Project
├── bin
│   ├── java
│   │   └── rampart
│   │       └── service
│   │           ├── SecureService.class
│   │           └── PWCBHandler.class
│   │
│   └── META-INF
│       └── services.xml
│
└── src
    ├── java
    │   └── rampart
    │       └── service
    │            ├── SecureService.java
    │            └── PWCBHandler.java
    │
    └── META-INF
        └── services.xml
```

i want to create the service archive for the above service and `jar -cvf SecureService.aar` is not working this scenario. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh finally got it. A missing * jar -cvf SecureService.aar * will do the magic.

Comment: If you solved this then add your response, we could upvote it and it will not be displayed as unanswered.